# What programming languages can be used with HTML?

Tags: html

I want to know which languages can be combined and how? But if I need to be more specific, What languages are compatible with HTML?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about why you're interested?  Is this a purely theoretical question, or are you trying to develop a particular application?

Comment: "Compatible" how?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Any separately-developed components can work together depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Not to be mean, but asking what languages are compatible with HTML is kind of a silly question. HTML is a markup language.

Comment: What I mean is, like CSS, javascript, PHP or Cold Fusion, these can be used in HTML. Are there any others? Can programming languages be used with HTML?

Comment: serverside: absolutely anything.  clientside: only javascript (assuming you mean programming languages)

Comment: @Javier Isn't there VBScript?

Comment: @yatta I think you are mixing things up. Server side languages like PHP or Cold Fusion *generate* HTML. CSS and Javascript are entirely different things, they are usually used in conjunction with HTML but they are not equal to it.

Comment: yatta obviously does not know how programming is to be done from HTML.  This question should not be closed - its just very basic.  Answers below are reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

HTML is not really "compatible" with anything.
HTML is markup that describes the **structure** of a document.
CSS describes the **style** of a document.
Javascript allows you to **manipulate** a document dynamically.

None of these are compatible with each other. A browser just brings them all together and applies them to a DOM, which together forms a website.

PHP, ColdFusion and other server side languages are way out in left field. They can be used to **generate** any of the above, but HTML doesn't know or care about them and neither does the browser. As such, there's no "compatibility". If a program can output text (virtually all programming languages can), it can generate HTML, CSS and Javascript.

The question is, **what is a browser capable of interpreting**, and the answer is HTML, CSS and Javascript. IE can do VBScript, too, but that doesn't really count. Using plugins, a browser could use any other number of languages.

Answer (score 2):

On the server side, as others have mentioned, you can use *any* language. HTML files are just text files, and any language can create text files. On the client side, however, you're limited to whatever is available in common browsers. This is pretty much:

- Javascript
- Actionscript (Flash)
- .NET languages (C#, etc) (Silverlight)
- Java (applets)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about the idea of server side versus client side scripts, programs, and languages.

HTML is translated by your browser into the visual pages that you see. As long as your browser is presented with some HTML, it will attempt to present it to you visually. On that note, it doesn't matter what has emitted that HTML.

The web server that consumes the HTTP request and responds with the HTML is just software. That software can be written in any language of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

The question's pretty vague, but here are some of the more common languages used for building web pages/web applications:

- PHP
- JavaScript (this one is client-side)
- ASP.NET with C# or VB
- Python
- Perl
- Ruby on Rails
- Java
- ActionScript

I could go on...

You can use any language server-side really.